# Why is joining a pandas series of strings faster with the built in string library than the pandas cat method?

Tags: python, pandas, string, performance

I needed to join a series of several thousand strings for a SQL query so my first instinct was to use the native python `str.join()` method after converting the series to a list.  However, after doing that I realized that there is mostly like a way to do this natively within pandas and I found `df.str.cat()`.

Running a quick `timeit` I found that `str.join()` does the job almost four times faster.  Can anyone explain the relatively large time discrepancy?

[image]

Here's a reproducible example.

```
val_list = pd.Series(pd._testing.rands_array(150, 1392))
%timeit str.join(",", val_list.tolist())
%timeit val_list.str.cat(sep=',')
```

Comment: [pandas.str.cat source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.4/pandas/core/strings.py#L2277-L2490) vs [python str.join source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/join.h). Python string library is written in cpython and pandas is dealing with the overhead of being pandas.